# Java error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, jgrasp

Doing a java project for CS class that entails us making a dec to binary converter with 2 classes (one being the tester). The teacher insists we don't contact him for help. Not really sure what I can do on this because it tells me "error: cannot find symbol" and points at the pn.charAt in the latter half of the code. Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Converter

```
public class BinaryNumber {
  private String n;

  public BinaryNumber(String pn) {
    n = pn;
  }


  public String getN() {
    return n;
  }



  public int convertToDecimal() {

    int bitPosition = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = n.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

      sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(2, bitPosition) * (pn.charAt + (i) - 48);
      //System.out.println(n.charAt (i));

    }
    return sum;
  }
  public int add(BinaryNumber obn) {
    return convertToDecimal() + obn.convertToDecimal();
  }
  public int sub(BinaryNumber obn) {
    return convertToDecimal() - obn.convertToDecimal();
  }

}
```

Test Class

```
public class BinaryNumberTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryNumber bn = new BinaryNumber("1011");
    BinaryNumber bn1 = new BinaryNumber("1111");


    System.out.println(bn.convertToDecimal());
    System.out.println(bn.add(b1));
  }

}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you **exactly** what is wrong: There is no variable `pn` in the class, so don't use variables that don't exist, and the constructor parameter doesn't count, since that is visible within the constructor only. Maybe you want to use the `n` variable instead?

Comment: Where is variable `pn` in `BinaryNumber` class?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pn` is defined as a parameter in your constructor `BinaryNumber()` so it has "local scope", it doesn't exist outside of the function.

What you should be using in `convertToDecimal()` would be your global variable `n` instead.

And if `pn` or `n` are Strings, then your usage of `charAt` is also incorrect since it is suppose to be a function. If I had to extrapolate, I think you're trying to use `i` as your `charAt()` positioning?

The changes to fix these two errors would look like this:

```
sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(2, bitPosition) * (n.charAt(i) - 48);
```

Comment: Not sure your implementation of `charAt` is correct. It is a method and the above should be resulting in compilation error. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: @BalwinderSingh thanks for picking up on that. I was fixated on the variable scope of `pn` I didn't notice what was in front of me. I've revised my answer now. Cheers.

Comment: For some reason this fix still doesn't work. It returns a number other than what the real conversion of a binary number is. For example, on the first construction "bn" it returns 3.

Comment: Just to be clear, @Jaskal, this question was in regards to the "cannot find symbol" issue. When you say the fix doesn't work, are you referring to the "symbol" issue or is this now a logic debugging problem? If it's the latter, then it's sort of out of scope for this particular question.